# How do I escape special characters in an NSString using RegexKitLite?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, regexkitlite

I'm constructing a regular expression that uses strings input by the user but the strings might contain special characters such as . \ or * and I want those to be treated as literals and not interpreted by their special meanings in the regex. I've tried this:

```
NSString *word = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:@"(\\P{L})" withString:@"\\$1"];
```

but the non letter characters are converted to '$1' instead of being prefixed with a backslash.  I've tried one and three backslashes in the second term but those give me an 'Unknown escape sequence' warning in XCode.  How can I print a backslash without RegexKitLite thinking that I'm escaping the dollar sign?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write the expression as you normally would and then replace each single backslash with two. Thus

```
\.
```

becomes

```
\\.
```

and

```
\\
```

becomes

```
\\\\
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  Four backslashes is what is needed in this case.  Don't know why I didn't try it in the first place.