# how to add tab space into UILabel.text

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have a UILabel instance, say mylabel.

What i want to do is like this:

```
mylabel.text = @"Age\tLimit\tYear"; 

instead of  

mylabel.text = @"Age           Limit       Year";
```

But when i tried, \t is not recognized. How to achieve it?

Comment: Use three labels with the proper spacing.

Comment: pass the text with the spaces u want between two words.

Comment: Can you try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386351/objective-c-code-to-right-pad-a-nsstring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also format string first

```
NSString *formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Age%8s%8s",[@"Limit" UTF8String], [@"Year" UTF8String]];

mylabel.text = formattedString;
```

Unfortunately, %@ formatter doesn't add spaces to adjust field width.
So I use UTF8String with %s specifier to adjust width.

Note:
Width specifies a minimum number of characters to output, and is typically used to pad fixed-width fields in tabulated output, where the fields would otherwise be smaller, although it does not cause truncation of oversized fields.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more backslash to it so it will be like this.

```
mylabel.text = @"Age\\tLimit\\tYear";
```

That way it won't be parsed as tab which is represented as "\t".

Here you have some more info: [How do I escape special characters in an NSString using RegexKitLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354606/how-do-i-escape-special-characters-in-an-nsstring-using-regexkitlite)
And here as well: [how to write special character in objective-C NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085116/how-to-write-special-character-in-objective-c-nsstring)